# In Rails, I am getting an error with fresh install of Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby on Rails I did a fresh install of Devise and I am getting this error when I go to my www.website.com/users/sign_in

```
undefined method `for' for #<Devise::ParameterSanitizer:0x007fad0fcf7b28> Did you mean? fork
```

Here is my application_controller.rb:

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name
  end
```

Any ideas?
I checked an I am running Devise Version 4.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using a newer version of devise. [they've updated their syntax](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters) since 3.x

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:signup) do |u|
  u.permit(:name)
end
```

becomes

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:signup, keys: [:name])
```